# Зачем нужна буферизация в php?

Tags: php

Не могу толком разобраться зачем нужна буферизация в php? Когда ее надо использовать?

Comment: буфер**и**зация

в основном когда требуется разовая обработка всего вывода или надо закэшировать вывод какого-то компонента.

Answer (score 1):

Что бы долго не писать) Гугл знает ответы на вопросы, просто нужно уметь правильно его спрашивать) http://sitear.ru/material/php-buferizaciya-vyvoda

Буферизация позволяет ускорить загрузку страницы в разы записывая данные в кеш клиента.